# SELECT string[] array of columns FROM Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dynamic

What I want to achieve is, from this:

```
string[] QueryString = new string[]{
        "Column1",
        "Column2"
    };
```

Create this:

```
SELECT  Column1,Column2
FROM    SomeTable
```

I know that I could do a `concat` but that's not a very clean way to doit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that I could do a concat but that's not a very clean way to do it.

Seems pretty clean to me:

```
string sql = "SELECT " + string.Join(", ", QueryString) + " FROM SomeTable";
```

Although you're susceptible to SQL injection attacks:

```
string[] QueryString = new string[]{
        " * FROM SomeTable; DROP TABLE SomeTable; --"
    };
```

So ONLY do this if you have complete control of the column names that can be used (e.g. populated from the table metadata).

Comment: I have full control of column names.

Comment: @skmasq Also, you probably want to safely quote the identifiers, e.g. `SELECT  [Column1], [Column2] FROM [SomeTable]`, otherwise a column name like `my column` would cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @qtext varchar(max) = 'select '+column1+ ' , '+column2+ ' from sometable ' 
Exec(@qtext)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.Format`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

```
String query =
String.Format("SELECT {0}, {1} FROM SomeTable", QueryString[0], QueryString[1]);
```

Although, as always when constructing sql queries, be aware of sql injection attacks.

Comment: this will not work when there is more than two columns

Comment: @PranayRana is right, it's dynamic array, thus tag `dynamic` :D